# iPhone for use in Israel

Tags: iphone

How can I get an iPhone to work in Israel and also transfer to it all the music and apps from my iPod?

I bought an unlocked 3GS iPhone and brought it to Israel. Initially, I put in my SIM card (from the company Cellcom) and it worked. Then, in order to get my apps and music, I restored the phone through Apple's service. After I did that, the SIM card no longer worked on the phone. I had no success unlocking the phone, so I am returning it to the seller. My question is:  what kind of phone should I get, and how can I transfer my apps and music to it without losing the ability to put in a SIM card?

Answer (score 1):

You need to buy officially unlocked iPhone. There is no universal way to tell if particular phone is officially unlocked until you restore it in iTunes and it's still unlocked.

[Here you can find countries/providers that sell unlocked phones](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1937) if that could be of any hep to you.